# ios sttwitter , after login not call to setOAuthToken in my view

Tags: ios, twitter

Hello in Ios i am using Sttwitter Api 
in view i call to twitter page and then user can login and after login call appDelegate page 
and in appDelegate.m file call to this function

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

   // NSLog(@"%@",url );
      NSLog(@"%@",[url scheme]);

     if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"fb1428424747377519"])
     {
         return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                       sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                             withSession:self.session];
         return YES;
     }

     else if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"myapp"])
     {
         NSDictionary *d = [self parametersDictionaryFromQueryString:[url query]];

         NSString *token = d[@"oauth_token"];
         NSString *verifier = d[@"oauth_verifier"];

         HomeViewController *vc = (HomeViewController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
         NSLog(@"%@",token);
         NSLog(@"%@",verifier);

         [vc setOAuthToken:token oauthVerifier:verifier];

         return YES;



     }else
     {
         return NO;
     }
```

in this code **[vc setOAuthToken:token oauthVerifier:verifier];** my app is cash 
in homeviewController.h i have add this method

```
- (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verfier;
```

and HomeViewController.m

```
- (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier {

    [_twitter postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {


        NSLog(@"-- screenName: %@", screenName);
        NSLog(@"-- userID: %@", userID);
        //name=screenName;

        //  [self saveYourDescription];
        //  [self timeline];





        // [self getimage];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {


        NSLog(@"-- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

}
```

and Error is

```
 2014-06-12 17:52:03.834[3302:90b] -[UINavigationController setOAuthToken:oauthVerifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10acc3af0
    2014-06-12 17:52:03.864[3302:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setOAuthToken:oauthVerifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10acc3af0'
```

please Help me

Comment: Please help me where i do mistake

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727872/1132951.  This will solve your problem

Comment: I think your vc is not of type "HomeViewController" but of type "UINavigationController" so the answer the link is referred will sure solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `vc` in not an instance of `HomeViewController` but `UINavigationController` instead.

You have to send the `setOAuthToken:oauthVerifier:` message to a `HomeViewController` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your **HomeViewController** not look like a "rootViewController", as @nst mentioned.

One possible solution is use `delegate` to call `setOAuthToken` method.

For this particular example you files will change as

Declare a `delegate` of `HomeViewController` in *AppDelegate.h* after `@interface`

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (assign) id home_delegate;
```

And in `AppDelegate.m` replace this line

```
HomeViewController *vc = (HomeViewController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
```

With

```
[home_delegate setOAuthToken:token oauthVerifier:verifier];
```

P.S: Don't forget to assign `delegate` to self in `HomeViewController`

Comment: plz explain me proper i have this type of error...?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Simple code and Just Replace with your Code It's Working

```
for (UIViewController *vc in ((UINavigationController *)[[self window] rootViewController]).viewControllers) {
            if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
                ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)vc;
                [viewController setOAuthToken:token oauthVerifier:verifier];
            }
        }
```